# Htmlunit fill form with javascript

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want fill https://login.live.com/ form but I coult not. I don't want use Chromium Embeded Framework or java Selenium. Because they opening a browser. Is there a way do it without open browser?

I tried HtmlUnit but javascript problem occurred:

```js
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.live.com/en");

final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("i0281");

final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("loginfmt");
textField.setValueAttribute("email");
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[loginfmt]
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByName(HtmlForm.java:572)

It is working html pages without javascript.

If you don't want code you can give me some hint. You can use this or you can google this framework ect...

Thank you